# Why can't chrome read local html file on android?

Tags: android, html, access-denied, android-chrome

When I open a html file the chrome( on android ) says that file is not readable. But I have given permissions to file and media for chrome.[image: My chrome browser when I open a html file]

Please help me to solve this! **Thank you!**

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use the "Desktop site" option in Chrome - it works on my machine.

I see you try to open a file from a SD card. You can copy them to the internal storage as the internal storage is not restricted and you can navigate to any folder from chrome. (for example - `Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/download`)

However, I strongly suggest using Desktop Chrome and viewing the html via "Developer Tools".